# Porque box-sizing no toma el hola mundo

Tags: html, css

Hola buenas noches soy principiante en desarrollo web he llegado a `css` y me tope con `normalize` y en el curso que estoy ponen `*{box-sizing: boder-box; padding: 0px; margin: 0px}` todo se alinea o se acopla.

El problema es que cuando yo lo puse no con todo me funciono solamente no me funciona con un `<h1>hola mundo</h1>`

Reinicie esa parte del código borre todo pero no me funciono.

El `<h1 class=“tamaño”>hola</h1>` Tiene en `html`

Ya en `css`

```
.tamaño {font-size: 25px; background-color: #a22; width: 10vw; height: 10vh}

.tamaño {font-family: ‘pacifico’ , cursive;} esto seria el tipo de letra

.tamaño {line-height: 2;}

.tamaño {font-weight: 900;}
```

Cuando dije que reinicié esa parte del código o eliminé, esto fue lo que eliminé

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De hecho, tengo q ser específico. Si quiero q me funcione, tengo q hacer esto:

`.tamaño {padding: 0; margin: 0;}`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? o ¿Cómo esperas que funcione?

Comment: No se lo que quieres conseguir, no lo entiendo, supongo que me falta tu html para entenderlo, pero si veo un error tipográfico: Donde pone `boder-box` deberia ser `border-box`. Por otra parte, aunque aparentemente funcione, no te recomiendo para nada usar nunca caracteres nacionales en cosas relativas a programación, como por ejemplo la clase `tamaño`, donde la ñ puede crear problemas inesperados en según que circunstancias.  Un detalle más, el código que pegas lo veo con formato, como si viniera de un word o algo asi... ¿con que estás editando tus html?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Ps simplemente que *{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

No me funciona con <h1>hola mundo</h1>

Si quiero q me funcione necesito añadirle el atributo por ejemplo:   .tamaño {padding: 0; margin: 0;}     Y lo que quiero es que me funcione con *{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir el código HTML y crear un [mcve] en la propia pregunta? También es importante que indiques a qué te refieres con "no funciona", ¿qué no funciona? ¿cómo debería funcionar? ¿cuál es el resultado que obtienes en su lugar?

Answer (score 0):

Tu código inicial funciona bien, a simple vista. Más abajo tienes un snippet (fragmento de código) que si lo ejecutas verás que funciona.

Los únicos cambios que he realizado han sido cambiar estas comillas que tu has puesto en tu pregunta:

```
<h1 class=“tamaño”>hola</h1>
```

por estas otras que son las correctas:

```
<h1 class="tamaño">hola</h1>
```

Y lo mismo para los apóstrofes. En tu pregunta pones estos:

```
.tamaño {font-family: ‘pacifico’ , cursive;}
```

y yo he puesto estos:

```
.tamaño {font-family: 'pacifico' , cursive;}
```

Lo que creo que te está ocurriendo es relacionado con tu editor de HTML/CSS, tal como te decia en los comentarios, que está poniendo una serie de comillas y apóstrofes que parecen con algún formato especial y eso quizás es lo que impide que se ejecute bien algo.

Revisa con que editor estás escribiendo el código, el cual debe escribir archivos en texto plano, y no con formato.

También, ante la duda, coge y copia este código que aparece a continuación sobre el que tu tienes y prueba de nuevo, a ver si ahora si funciona.

```css
.tamaño {font-size: 25px; background-color: #a22; width: 25vw; height: 20vh}

.tamaño {font-family: 'pacifico' , cursive;} 

.tamaño {line-height: 2;}

.tamaño {font-weight: 900;}

*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

```html
<h1 class="tamaño">hola mundo</h1>
```

Nota: La sintaxis es **muy importante** cuando programas en cualquier lenguage y debes respetarla al 100%. Un fallo de un solo caracter puede dar al traste con todo el resto. Revisa bien lo que escribas y usa las herramientas correctas para ello.

Comment: Sublime text es donde estoy escribiendo el código no hay nigeriano error en el código, no esta mal escrito, se que te lo estoy escribiendo mal porque no son los signos correctos pero en el código están de maravilla

Comment: Que raro pues, yo tambien uso Sublime Text con el fuente Fira Code y cuando pego mi código aquí no me salen esos signos distintos.  ¿Ves algo distinto en mi respuesta que en tu código aparte de eso?  ¿sigue saliendote mal? ¿Si ejecutas el snippet de mi respuesta no es lo que esperas?

Comment: Am creo no fui claro, mira te escribo desde mi teléfono por eso el significado de esos signos, los signos que me diste tu si están en mi código, por otra parte necesito señalar al hola mundo con el ejemplo que te di de .tamaño  {padding: 0; margin: 0;} solo asi me funciona, pero quiero sacarme de dudas el poque no me funciona con el otro para evitarme hacer el ejemplo que te di.